# Javamail throwing java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException with charset="iso-2022-cn"

Tags: exception, jakarta-mail

I have an eml that has the following charset info.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-2022-cn"
```

While reading no issues, but when i write the same eml back to disk, i get the following error, any ideas?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at sun.nio.cs.ext.ISO2022_CN.newEncoder(ISO2022_CN.java:76) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.<init>(StreamEncoder.java:176) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:59) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:100) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.writeTo(text_plain.java:161) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1486) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:865) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:462) ~[bin/:?]
at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1486) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:865) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:462) ~[bin/:?]
at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1486) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1773) ~[bin/:?]
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1749) ~[bin/:?]
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with the JDK's support of that charset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a charset which does not support encoding<sup>[[1]](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4737614) [[2]](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1007)</sup>, only decoding.

So you'll need to set the output header to UTF-8 when writing out the message.